# Insert fragment from one module to template in another - thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I need some help. I have let say three maven modules: `moduleMain`, `moduleCore`, `module2`, `module3`. I have in `moduleCore` simple `html` file, eg. `Share.html` which has some `html` code inside. And now I want to use `Share.html` in my `module1` and `module2` in `Thymeleaf` templates How to bite it?

I search in documentation, but unfortunately, I found only `include`, `insert` which examples are only when we have all in one place. This not works for me.

`Thymeleaf` version: `3.0.9.RELEASE`, I use them with `Spring`.

**Solution**

I found solution, only need to add all `HTML` files to default folder: `web-inf/templates` and it works.